# Business plan/finance planning tool for freelance work

Tags: osx, finance

I am looking for a software tool that makes my life easier when it comes to planning finances for a freelance business. I need to:

- keep track of daily, monthly and yearly expenses, such as cost of living, insurances
- project yearly/monthly income and profit
- calculate taxes and insurance premiums as a percentage of income or profit
- generate reports that help me understand the viability and profitability

The answer may well be a good spreadsheet template, or some personal finance app, but I haven't found what I'm looking for so far. As a freelancer, I do not need the tool to generate a shiny business plan that looks good to an investor, just to help me with my internal calculation.